# how to remove duplicates from sql server based on string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

removing duplicates from SQL table

example :
i/p :

```
EID EName ....  ERole    
1    Nani       SQL    
2    Nani       SQL Developer     
3    Suresh     ASP .Net Developer     
4    Suresh     ASP .Net    
5    Ravi       Sales Force    
6    Ravi       Sales Force developer
```

i have data set like above ,

Output :

```
EID EName ....  ERole     
2    Nani       SQL Developer     
3    Suresh     ASP .Net Developer     
6    Ravi       Sales Force developer
```

Note above one is example :

in `ERole` column , if first 10 characters are matched it should be a duplicate .

Comment: *"in ERole column , if first 10 characters are matched it should be a duplicate ."* So why is SQL then a duplicate?

Comment: select * from #Table1 where designation like '%Developer%'

Comment: above one is just a example,

Comment: senior Architect

senior Architect PMP 101 

senior Architect new PMP

Comment: senior Architect,senior Architect PMP 101 ,senior Architect new PMP i have a roles like above , as per my requirement in these three roles first 10 characters are same so only i have to consider 1 record –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First im going to set up your example so you can test it.

```
CREATE TABLE #example
(
    EID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    EName VARCHAR(100),
    ERole VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO 
    #example
VALUES
    ('Nani','SQL'),
    ('Nani','SQL Developer'),
    ('Suresh','ASP .Net Developer'),
    ('Suresh','ASP .Net'),
    ('Ravi','Sales Force'),
    ('Ravi','Sales Force developer')
```

Now, if you want to delete duplicated record by your criteria(Same Ename, Same first 10 chars in ERole) u can use this:

```
WITH grouped_example as (
SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ename, SUBSTRING(ERole,0,10) ORDER BY ERole DESC) as preserve,
        EID
    FROM #example
)
DELETE FROM grouped_example where preserve <> 1
```

If u want to SELECT with no duplicates u can use this:

```
WITH grouped_example as (
SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ename, SUBSTRING(ERole,0,10) ORDER BY ERole DESC) as preserve,
        *
    FROM #example
)
SELECT EID,EName,ERole FROM grouped_example where preserve = 1
```

*Note: I use ORDER BY ERole DESC so that we stay with the role with more information (more characters)
*Note 2: you can change the number of characters you need to match, changing the last value of SUBSTRING()

Answer (score 1):

> in ERole column , if first 10 characters are matched it should be a duplicate

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(EROle, 10) ORDER BY EID) RN
  FROM T
)
DELETE T 
FROM CTE INNER JOIN T
ON CTE.EID = T.EID
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

according to data set if name is strict to one role then below will work

```
with cte as
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by ename order by ename) rn
from table_name
) delete from cte where rn>1
```

Comment: senior Architect,senior Architect PMP 101 ,senior Architect new PMP i have a roles like above , as per my requirement in these three roles first 10 characters are same so only i have to consider 1 record –

Answer (score 0):

For your data, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ename = t.ename and
                        t.erole like t2.erole + '%' and
                        t.eid < t2.eid
                 );
```

This doesn't include the "first ten characters" restriction.  But I suspect it actually does what you want.

Comment: senior Architect,senior Architect PMP 101 ,senior Architect new PMP
i have a roles like above , as per my requirement in these three roles first 10 characters are same so only i have to consider 1 record

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the data set this should be working for you!

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
EID int,
ENAME VARCHAR(20),
EROLE  VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1,'NANI','SQL'),
        (2,'NANI','SQL DEVELOPER'),
        (3,'Suresh','ASP .NET Developer'),
        (4,'Suresh', 'ASP .Net'),
        (5, 'Ravi', 'Sales Force'),
        (6, 'Ravi', 'Sales Force developer');

DELETE FROM test
WHERE EID IN(
SELECT EID FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ENAME ORDER BY LEN(EROLE) DESC) as RN
from #test) tab1 WHERE RN != 1);

SELECT * FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 with cte as
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by LEFT(EROle, 10) order by left(EROle, 10) rn
from  T
) delete from cte where rn=1
```